# How do I use a function from a library?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, noise

I have to use a noise function from the library Noise.js. How would I go about adding the library to my file so that it is called?

Here is the small section that calls it.

```
//Use noise.js library to generate a grid of 2D simplex noise values
try {
  noise.seed(Math.random());
}
catch(err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
```

Here is the link to the ThreeJS file that uses the noise function to create 3D curl noise.
https://al-ro.github.io/projects/embers/embers.js

Here is the Noise library
https://github.com/josephg/noisejs

Comment: Did you have a look at the page source to see how the demo page was built?

Comment: I did, it links to just the source code for the JS file. Not the entire setup. Here is the link. https://al-ro.github.io/projects/embers/embers.js

Comment: @Yerbs What do you mean "the entire setup"? Are you not trying to import that same noise library?

Answer (score 0):

Just do like in [their example](https://github.com/josephg/noisejs/blob/master/demo.html).
Import the library using HTML `<script>` tags (before your own code), and then the object `noise` will be available to you as a global variable.